# How to find the roots of $x^6-2x^5+3x^4-2x^3+2x-1$?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I want to find the roots of the sextic

$$ x^6 - 2x^5 + 3x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x - 1 $$

I have plotted the function and found two "fractional" real roots $0.5698$ and $-0.75487$. Since these are not exact roots, I can not do polynomial division to reduce the degree.

The other $4$ roots should be imaginary.  How to get those imaginary roots? Is there any roots with absolute value $> 1$?

I think we have to solve using numerical method. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If cheating is allowed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=factor+x%5E6-2x%5E5%2B3x%5E4-2x%5E3%2B2x-1 shows that the polynomial factors nicely into two 3rd degree polynomials.

Comment: Are you giving us the problem in the same way it was given to you?

Comment: @MartinR, thank you. I was not aware using wolfram. Now I got it

Comment: *“Is there any roots with absolute value >1?”*  – Yes, because their product is equal to $-1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, it is not like that. I have drawn function and got two real roots and was unable to find the others

Comment: "imaginary roots" are those on the imaginary axis. What numerical methods do you know? Newton's method with a complex initial point like $1+i$ followed by deflation by the root found and its complex conjugate should work. Using Laguerre's method with deflation (using the conjugate roots property) does not even need a complex initial point. More exotic would be the Bairstow method (finding quadratic factors) or Durand-Kerner (finding all roots simultaneously).

Comment: For an exact expression for the real root of $x^3-x^2+1$, Cardano's formula gives
$$x = \frac13(\sqrt[3]{\frac{-25+\sqrt{621}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{-25-\sqrt{621}}{2}} + 1)\approx -0.75487766\dots$$

Comment: We have $f(x)=(x^3-x^2+x)^2-(x-1)^2.$ This leads to the factorization.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same as @Martin R
$$x^6 - 2 x^5 + 3 x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x - 1=\left(x^3-x^2+1\right) \left(x^3-x^2+2 x-1\right)$$

$x^3-x^2+1=0$ has only one real root given by
$$x=\frac 13  \left(1-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{25}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

$x^3-x^2+2 x-1=0$ has only one real root given by
$$x=\frac 13  \left( 1+2 \sqrt{5} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{10 \sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\right)$$ I just followed the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root).

Now, you reduce the problem to two quadratic equations and obtain the analytical expressions for the complex roots.

I think that is is worth to know and practice this hyperbolic method since the probability than a cubic equation has one real root is about $0.875$.